# Type 'NamedNodeMap' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator

Tags: typescript

I've got a project building with the latest TS (5.1.3) but the compiler is complaining with

`Type 'NamedNodeMap' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator`.

I'm looking to iterate over `Element.attributes`. Any idea what option I'm missing ? I can't reproduce this on the playground (as expected since this issue has been [fixed in 2018](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20937))

Comment: what's your tsconffig lib

Comment: Probably you nee `lib: [..., DOM.Iterable]` as it's not included in Dom

Comment: @Dimava Yeah, it was `dom.iterable`. You can make it an answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing `dom.iterable` in the tsconfig `lib`.